# Background image not showing on iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, css, ipad, background

I want to create a section with a background covering it in a mobile web page, so I was using the following CSS code:

```
#section1{
    background: url("background1.png") auto 749px;
    height: 749px;
}
```

The background is showing correctly on Android (Chrome, Firefox ...), but it is not showing at all on iPhone or iPad (Safari, Chrome iOS ...). I have tried to set these properties using jQuery when the DOM is ready, but no luck. I read that the size might be a problem, but the image is about 700kB (1124x749px) so it should accomplish the [Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15) rules. Which is the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a problem with your CSS rule:

Your using the shorthand notation in which the `background-size`-property comes *after* the `background-position`-property and *it must be separated by a `/`*.

What you're trying to do is to set the position, but it will fail as `auto` is not a valid value for it.

To get it to work in shorthand notation it has to look like this:

```
background: url([URL]) 0 0 / auto 749px;
```

Also note that there's a value called `cover`, which may be suitable and more flexible here:

```
background: url([URL]) 0 0 / cover;
```

The **support** for `background-size` in the shorthand notation is also not very broad, as it's supported in Firefox 18+, Chrome 21+, IE9+ and Opera. It is not supported in Safari at all. Regarding this, I would suggest to always use:

```
background: url("background1.png");
background-size: auto 749px; /* or cover */
```

Here are a few examples and a demo, to demonstrate that behavior. You'll see that Firefox for example shows every image except the fist one. Safari on the other hand shows only the last.

**CSS**

```
section {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

#section1 {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) auto 100px;
}

#section2 {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) 0 0 / auto 100px;
}

#section3 {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) 0 0 / cover;
}

#section4 {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) 0 0;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/kDjNA/)

**Further reading**

[MDN CSS reference "background"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)
[MDN CSS reference "background-size"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

> **<'background-size'>**
>   See [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).
>   This property must be specified after background-position, separated with the '/' character.

Comment: Its not really fix for iPad or iPhone, its limited

Comment: @TejasTank Can you explain, what you mean?

Comment: Given solution note, not fix safari or ipad issue, also written in answer, really it not working too

Comment: It does't matter even 1000 year ago corrected, in contex to Questation, Answer marked is wrong. Its matter only worked in iPad or iPhone.

Comment: @TejasTank I still don't understand what you mean by saying: "*Its matter only worked in iPad or iphone*". The OP's problem was that he used the shorthand notation wrongly. If this isn't the case in your situation, you might ask another question, so that somebody can help you.

Comment: No arguments, in context to questation, answer is wrong so I downvoted, Also absulte not perfect answer for given problem domain. Even I tested it did not work.

Answer (score 20):

My problem was that iOS doesn't support `background-attachment: fixed`. Removing that line made the image appear.

It looks like there are workarounds for a fixed background image though: [How to replicate background-attachment fixed on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios)

Comment: help me out also check if you don't have multiple media queries  pointing to the same screensize. I overlooked an aspect-ratio

Answer (score 7):

I hope this will help someone in despair.
In my case, it was the size of the image that was too big, so the iPad just wasn't loading it (and it was right actually).

Diminishing its size and quality solved the loading issue.

Answer (score 6):

The problem was not solved when I tried to use properly the background in shorthand. It works when I split the background property:

```
#section1{
    background: url("background1.png");
    background-size: auto 749px;
    height: 749px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the image size if nothing else works -- iOS doesn't like large image sizes on mobile and simply won't display the image if it's too large.

Great fundamentals by @insertusernamehere! No matter what I did I couldn't get my image to show up...until, I went back to basics. The image size was too large and iPhone didn't like loading an image of that size, over 700kbs. So, I reduced it to 32kb and we were in action.

Answer (score 1):

Background image disappears on the IOS Browser (iPhone/iPad).
This is the code i used:

```
/*CSS*/
.bg-image {
    background: url([URL]) center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, img src works on all browsers. It adds the Background Images acc to devices resolution.

```
<div class="download">
  <picture>
    <source srcset="/images/ios-device-mobile-v2.png" media="(max-width:450px)"/>
     <source srcset="/images/ios-device-mobile-v2.png" media="(min-width: 600px)"/>
    <img src="/images/ios-device.png" class="imgright">
  </picture>
</div>
```

This piece of code is tested on iPhone Safari, Android Chrome and web Safari. Hopefully, This will help.

Answer (score 1):

`background-attachment: fixed;` is not supported by IOS.

You can fix this by keeping the image in the div and positioning the div.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had an negative text-indent that was throwing my background image off the page, so color:Transparent it is then.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anyone specifically say this, but you have to define the width too. Makes since, since I set the background size to "contain" - it has to know what the container's dimensions are.

Once I did, the background rendered as expected.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:599px) {
  [id=banner] td { width:480px !important; height:223px !important; background:url('image') no-repeat 0 0 !important; }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:479px) {
  [id=banner] td { width:320px !important; height:149px !important; background:url('image') no-repeat 0 0 !important; background-size:contain !important; }
}
```

Note: The background URL needs to be defined for both breakpoints so that it works for iPhone 5 (iOS7).

Answer (score 0):

Add a background-color solved my problem

```
background-color: #F4F4F2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to set `input { opacity: 0; }` for my `input + span {}` icon to show up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a real solution/reason for my similar issue but my background-image PNG image simply wouldn't show up until I moved it to a new folder in my (Cordova) iPad app. I literally moved it from /css/images/sweden/myimage.png to /css/images/sv/myimage.png and it started working. The other odd thing is that ALL other images in the original folder work fine (as background-image). Super strange. If I find the true reason/fix I'll report back.

Answer (score 0):

I tried resizing my background image, made it way too small to test the theory, but it still wouldn’t show on any browser on the iPad (and presumably an iPhone). Tried other solutions that are listed here – still no good. Then I noticed that the element had inherited `display: table;`. Added `display: block;` to override that and the background image now displays on all divices that I've tested it on.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old issue, i would like to share my solution here. iOS bigger image than the dimension ignores rendering, please use appropriate use size, not the css height/width. The actual image should not be more than 150% larger in size than the rendering viewpoint.