# Background Image on Chrome and Safari for iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

Has anyone found a solution for making a background image cover the entire div section on iOS? Code words perfectly on android. I am looking for a CSS solution

```
background: url('../img/slide/contact_background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-ms-background-size:cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing "fixed" since it's probably causing the problem with iOS:

```
background: url('../img/slide/contact_background.jpg') no-repeat center center;
```

This should work on both Android and iOS browsers.

There is some more info here (and brief testing shows that it's not better in the iOS8): [How to replicate background-attachment fixed on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios)