# Background-attachment: fixed is not working in iPad

Tags: html, css, background

I use this css button working  background-attachment: fixed;in ipad.
    please help me.Below the link

[Link is here](http://artfacets.com/Aesthatic_wp/)

```
.home #bottom-header {
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-image: url("images/hero_bg.jpg");
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: what button you taking about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replicate background-attachment fixed on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios)

Answer (score 1):

This process is quite costly to the render process on mobile browsers so it is disabled.

See this post:
[How to replicate background-attachment fixed on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a workaround, but looks way better than a `fixed` background, in my opinion. Just add `data-speed="1"` if you want to fix-position it.

http://codepen.io/AartdenBraber/pen/WpaxZg