# Background image on phones looks shrinked

Tags: html, css, background-image

What changes do I implement so that the backgound image Back.jpg show fulls screen and the content scrolls, rigth now it only works on desktops 
The content should scroll with the image remain full screen

the image is 1500 width by 1000 height, in phones the image looks shrinked, but on desktops looks fine.

```
<style>
    html, body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        border:0;
        height:100%;
        background: url(Back.jpg) center no-repeat fixed;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You are using `background-attachment: fixed;` which does not work that well on iOS (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios) for why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
    html, body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        border:0;
        height:100%;
        background: url(Back.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: it doesnt work still looks bad, is it the image size? 1500 px w by 1000 pc height

Answer (score 0):

`background-size:cover;` will work with a media query perhaps