# Background image background-attachment: fixed; issue on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, safari

I have a template which has a background image with `background-attachment: fixed;` in the header. Please see the link attached:

http://simpleqode.com/preview/wolfram/2.2.2/index_crossfading.html

```
body.classic .welcome_classic {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(../img/bg-pattern_alt.png), url(../img/screen-bg_11.jpg);
  background-position: top left, center center;
  background-size: auto, cover;
  background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
}
```

The problem is that on iPhone the background image gets 'zoomed' multiple times you can't see the image.

[image]

Removing `background-attachment: fixed;` resolves the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you seeing? I'm seeing this which looks normal http://jerrylow.com/demo/stackoverflow/38619441.png

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios

Comment: I see - are you testing in iOS7?

Comment: @jerrylow, I tested it on iPhone 6s on BrowserStack and got what attached :-(

Comment: @jtmingus, they suggest to include another div with position: fixed; I was hoping to something with the original container.

Comment: @Deka87 I'm not sure how accurate your results are. I also tested on a real device and not seeing the issue. This is also from browser stack on iPhone 6s http://jerrylow.com/demo/stackoverflow/38619441-2.png

Comment: @jerrylow that's weird, because this is what I get (attached to the post). Maybe you chose Chrome (although I doubt).

Comment: @Deka87 nope the Chrome browser controls are on the top and I just tested in Chrome as well and everything is well.

Comment: @Deka87 but it does talk about how having a `fixed` background is disabled for iOS because the repainting is two expensive, which is why they were looking for a workaround

Comment: @jtmingus, yeah I remember john Irish mentioning this. It's just disabled on many mobiles(and pads)