# Background Image becomes grey in iOS / not showing

Tags: html, css

My background image is not showing on iOS devices, it becomes grey.

I can't test it on windows and also can't afford to upload every 10 sec a new fix.

I found many different answers on internet, I already tried some but none of them worked for me.

Here is my CSS code:

```
.img-bg-index {
    background-image: url("../img/Monteurzimmer-BG.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center right;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 95vh;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: can you also add your HTML code?

Comment: jsfiddle would be better.

Comment: Nevermind, it was the background-attachment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replicate background-attachment fixed on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background attachement caused the problem, it seems that it is disabled in safari browsers:

[How to replicate background-attachment fixed on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios)

I used a media query and changed the background-attachment to initial on a certain max-width:

```
@media ( max-width :856px) {
    .img-bg-index {
        background-attachment: initial;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15043738)

Comment: there is an answer I thought? Dont use this style because it is disabled in safari browsers