# CSS position fixed does not appear on mobile

Tags: css

I have an element like with this css:

```
element.style {
    background-image: url(image.jpg);
}
.panel-image {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

I am now trying to make it a fixed position, so when i try to do the following:

```
.panel-image {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

The element no longer appears on the page.

There is an element that wraps around this element:

```
.twentyseventeen-panel {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<article id="panel1" class="twentyseventeen-panel  post-47 page type-page status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry">


        <div class="panel-image" style="background-image: url(https://2017.wordpress.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/pexels-photo-30724-2000x1200.jpg);">
            <div class="panel-image-prop" style="padding-top: 60%"></div>
        </div><!-- .panel-image -->


    <div class="panel-content">
        <div class="wrap">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h2 class="entry-title">Our Drinks</h2>

            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <div class="entry-content">
                <h2>Coffee and Espresso</h2>
<p><strong>Drip Coffee</strong>&nbsp;$2.50</p>
<p><strong>Espresso Shots</strong> $3.00</p>
<p><strong>Americano</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Cappuccino</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Macchiato</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Cortado</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Flat White</strong>&nbsp;$5.00</p>
<p><strong>Latte</strong>&nbsp;$4.50<br>
<em>hot or iced</em></p>
<p><strong>Mocha</strong>&nbsp;$4.50<br>
<em>hot or iced</em></p>
<p><strong>Cold Brew</strong> $4.00<br>
<em>regular or nitro</em></p>
<h2>Other Drinks</h2>
<p><strong>Chai</strong><strong>&nbsp; </strong>$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Iced Tea&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>$3.50<br>
<em>green, black, or white</em></p>
<p><strong>Hot Tea</strong><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>$3.00<br>
<em>english breakfast, ceylon, green, white, chamomile, rooibos, peach</em></p>
<p><strong>Flavored Sodas</strong><strong>&nbsp; </strong>$4.00<br>
<em>raspberry, blueberry, peach, mango, vanilla, mint</em></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->


        </div><!-- .wrap -->
    </div><!-- .panel-content -->

</article>
```

My question is, how do I get the element with the background image to be fixed.

Here is an example site:

http://www.grogenex.com/

Comment: what are you trying to do with a `position: fixed` in mobile? are trying to retain the parallax look in mobile?

Comment: I want the parallax effect on mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New Answer:**

if you add the CSS to the image. It creates the parallax effect you need!

```
background-attachment: fixed;
position: fixed !important;
object-fit: cover;
height:100%;
```

It should be inserted in the `image` element as so.

```
<img src="http://www.grogenex.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/cropped-canabis.jpg" width="2000" height="1200" alt="Grogenex" srcset="http://www.grogenex.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/cropped-canabis.jpg 2000w, http://www.grogenex.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/cropped-canabis-300x180.jpg 300w, http://www.grogenex.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/cropped-canabis-768x461.jpg 768w, http://www.grogenex.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/cropped-canabis-1024x614.jpg 1024w" sizes="100vw" style="
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: fixed !important;
    object-fit: cover;
    height:100%;
">
```

Also if you add this to the `.panel-image` it will create the same parallax for mobile also!

```
.panel-image{
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
}
```

Please let me know if this fixes your issue!

**Old Answer:**

In the initial CSS you provided in the question the image was already fixed. Are you trying to achieve something like this?

```css
.panel-image {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}

.twentyseventeen-panel {
    position: relative;
}
.entry-content{
 margin-top:200px;
}
```

```html
<article id="panel1" class="twentyseventeen-panel  post-47 page type-page status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry">


        <div class="panel-image" style="background-image: url(https://2017.wordpress.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/pexels-photo-30724-2000x1200.jpg);">
            <div class="panel-image-prop" style="padding-top: 60%"></div>
        </div><!-- .panel-image -->


    <div class="panel-content">
        <div class="wrap">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h2 class="entry-title">Our Drinks</h2>

            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <div class="entry-content">
                <h2>Coffee and Espresso</h2>
<p><strong>Drip Coffee</strong>&nbsp;$2.50</p>
<p><strong>Espresso Shots</strong> $3.00</p>
<p><strong>Americano</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Cappuccino</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Macchiato</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Cortado</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Flat White</strong>&nbsp;$5.00</p>
<p><strong>Latte</strong>&nbsp;$4.50<br>
<em>hot or iced</em></p>
<p><strong>Mocha</strong>&nbsp;$4.50<br>
<em>hot or iced</em></p>
<p><strong>Cold Brew</strong> $4.00<br>
<em>regular or nitro</em></p>
<h2>Other Drinks</h2>
<p><strong>Chai</strong><strong>&nbsp; </strong>$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Iced Tea&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>$3.50<br>
<em>green, black, or white</em></p>
<p><strong>Hot Tea</strong><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>$3.00<br>
<em>english breakfast, ceylon, green, white, chamomile, rooibos, peach</em></p>
<p><strong>Flavored Sodas</strong><strong>&nbsp; </strong>$4.00<br>
<em>raspberry, blueberry, peach, mango, vanilla, mint</em></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->


        </div><!-- .wrap -->
    </div><!-- .panel-content -->

</article>
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to take that code out, I don't want to use background-attached

Comment: @user979331 so you want to completely remove the image of the cup?

Comment: Wow, this really messes everything up

Comment: @user979331 if you provide the webpage it can be resolved sooner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153058/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-user979331).

Comment: @user979331 Sorry for the late response - I didn't get a method to do it - until now, can you please check my updated answer!

Comment: I just tried your answer and my image does not appear.

Comment: @user979331 if we can connect offline so that I can understand the problem it would be great

Comment: Okay, shoot me a direct message.

Comment: @user979331 Sorry, I don't know how to to it, I am online now, can you ping me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154150/discussion-between-user979331-and-naren-murali).

Answer (score 4):

This is another approach for that, it does not use "background-attachment" or "position: fixed".

```css
.panel-image {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.twentyseventeen-panel {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
}
.panel-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.panel-content > .wrap {
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<article id="panel1" class="twentyseventeen-panel  post-47 page type-page status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry">


        <div class="panel-image" style="background-image: url(https://2017.wordpress.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/pexels-photo-30724-2000x1200.jpg);">
            <div class="panel-image-prop" style="padding-top: 60%"></div>
        </div><!-- .panel-image -->


    <div class="panel-content">
        <div class="wrap">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h2 class="entry-title">Our Drinks</h2>

            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <div class="entry-content">
                <h2>Coffee and Espresso</h2>
<p><strong>Drip Coffee</strong>&nbsp;$2.50</p>
<p><strong>Espresso Shots</strong> $3.00</p>
<p><strong>Americano</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Cappuccino</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Macchiato</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Cortado</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Flat White</strong>&nbsp;$5.00</p>
<p><strong>Latte</strong>&nbsp;$4.50<br>
<em>hot or iced</em></p>
<p><strong>Mocha</strong>&nbsp;$4.50<br>
<em>hot or iced</em></p>
<p><strong>Cold Brew</strong> $4.00<br>
<em>regular or nitro</em></p>
<h2>Other Drinks</h2>
<p><strong>Chai</strong><strong>&nbsp; </strong>$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Iced Tea&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>$3.50<br>
<em>green, black, or white</em></p>
<p><strong>Hot Tea</strong><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>$3.00<br>
<em>english breakfast, ceylon, green, white, chamomile, rooibos, peach</em></p>
<p><strong>Flavored Sodas</strong><strong>&nbsp; </strong>$4.00<br>
<em>raspberry, blueberry, peach, mango, vanilla, mint</em></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->


        </div><!-- .wrap -->
    </div><!-- .panel-content -->

</article>
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question, are you trying to do this?

```css
.panel-image {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
.twentyseventeen-panel {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.panel-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 200px;
  padding: 0.1em 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<article id="panel1" class="twentyseventeen-panel  post-47 page type-page status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry">


        <div class="panel-image" style="background-image: url(https://2017.wordpress.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/pexels-photo-30724-2000x1200.jpg);">
            <div class="panel-image-prop" style="padding-top: 60%"></div>
        </div><!-- .panel-image -->


    <div class="panel-content">
        <div class="wrap">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h2 class="entry-title">Our Drinks</h2>

            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <div class="entry-content">
                <h2>Coffee and Espresso</h2>
<p><strong>Drip Coffee</strong>&nbsp;$2.50</p>
<p><strong>Espresso Shots</strong> $3.00</p>
<p><strong>Americano</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Cappuccino</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Macchiato</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Cortado</strong>&nbsp;$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Flat White</strong>&nbsp;$5.00</p>
<p><strong>Latte</strong>&nbsp;$4.50<br>
<em>hot or iced</em></p>
<p><strong>Mocha</strong>&nbsp;$4.50<br>
<em>hot or iced</em></p>
<p><strong>Cold Brew</strong> $4.00<br>
<em>regular or nitro</em></p>
<h2>Other Drinks</h2>
<p><strong>Chai</strong><strong>&nbsp; </strong>$4.50</p>
<p><strong>Iced Tea&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>$3.50<br>
<em>green, black, or white</em></p>
<p><strong>Hot Tea</strong><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>$3.00<br>
<em>english breakfast, ceylon, green, white, chamomile, rooibos, peach</em></p>
<p><strong>Flavored Sodas</strong><strong>&nbsp; </strong>$4.00<br>
<em>raspberry, blueberry, peach, mango, vanilla, mint</em></p>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->


        </div><!-- .wrap -->
    </div><!-- .panel-content -->

</article>
```

Comment: Images still do not appear

Comment: In which part of your html is this "element"? I did not find it.

Answer (score 3):

Just simply use `background-attachment: fixed;` this will create a simple parallax effect in mobile without `JavaScript` though just make sure it appends on mobile:

```
// make sure this is mobile width
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .panel-image {
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
}
```

and there you go.

Comment: Background-attachment: fixed; doesn't work on iPhone 7

Comment: `background-attachment` do not work on mobile safari at all. [see related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios) unless you are willing to implement at JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to achieve a parallax effect. Unfortunately, it is not achievable with applying position:fixed. Just like what others have mentioned, background-attachment:fixed might help.

Here's a good resource for achieving a pure css parallax/semi-parallax http://thetotobox.com/blog/easy-pure-css-parallax-effect-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

Well, what you are trying to do is have your mobile version retain the parallax effect like the desktop version, while maintaining responsiveness for cross0browser support. The ability to keep parallax effect on mobile can be achieved with the following CSS property added to your current code, background-attachment. This will state whether the image should move or stay at a fixed position in regards to the viewport, or when a user scrolls on your site. No extra code needed.

```css
.panel-image {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Hope this helps in your endeavors.

Answer (score 0):

> The **background-attachment** property sets whether a background image
>   is fixed or scrolls with the rest of the page.

So instead of `position: fixed;` in your code, do `background-attachment: fixed;`...

```
.panel-image {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```