# Background Attachment "fixed" not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

Background Attachment "fixed" not working in safari browser.

Here is my site link
http://agozee.com/petermelcher/

Background Attachment - fixed is working well in chrome and mozila but it is not working in safari browser.

Can any one help me to out this issue?

Comment: It's working fine in my mac...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replicate background-attachment fixed on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios)