# Fixed full screen background image on Iphone acts weird

Tags: html, css

I try to have 4 full-screen background image ( i think it's called hero section) on my page. 
I used this style for every row with full-screen background.

```
.kimiabg {
    background: url(http://kimia-tak.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/s2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 2rem 0;
}
```

everything is fine. unless showing background on iphone. it is blurry. I really do not know what is the problem.

[image]

you can check the live website here : http://kimia-tak.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background-attachment: fixed;` is the problem. This is not really supported on iOS Safari.

> **Can I use `background-attachment` ?**
>
> iOS Safari:
>
> - Partial support refers to supporting local but not fixed
> - Only supports local when -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch is not used
>
> *https://caniuse.com/#search=background-attachment*

For more information and workarounds you can look at the answer from *@fernandopasik* to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23420490/7426156