# background image not displaying on phone

Tags: android, css, background-image

Working on new page with background image.  Displays fine on desktops and tablets but fails on android phones.

```
body {
background: url("images/bk1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
-moz-background-size: 100% auto;
-o-background-size: 100% auto;
background-size: 100% auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked before but it was about IOS: [How to replicate background-attachment fixed on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios)

I Think the problem related to background-attachment fixed, so i think you need to make it like this:

*notice: the property of background-attachment won't work on mobile

```css
body {
background: url("images/bk1.jpg") no-repeat center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
-moz-background-size: 100% auto;
-o-background-size: 100% auto;
background-size: 100% auto;
 }
```