# Fixed background on scroll on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a problem with fixed background in a specific section of a Wordpress website I'm working on. [Here's the link](http://yeganehhosseininia.com/#biography)

The background is fixed on PC, but on iOS and chrome android its not fixed and will scroll with content.

I've set these custom CSS for `#biography` Section but still doesn't work:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
#biography {
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(0,0,0,.3)), url(http://yeganehhosseininia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Yeganeh3.jpg) center center !important;
webkit-background-position: center center !important;
-moz-background-position: center center !important;
-o-background-position: center center !important;
background-position: center center !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
-webkit-background-size: cover !important;
-moz-background-size: cover !important;
-o-background-size: cover !important;
background-size: cover !important;
-webkit-background-attachment: fixed !important;
-moz-background-attahcment: fixed !important;
-o-background-attachment: fixed !important;
background-attachment: fixed !important;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
#biography {
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(0,0,0,.3)), url(http://yeganehhosseininia.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Yeganeh2.jpg) !important;
-webkit-background-position: center center !important;
-moz-background-position: center center !important;
-o-background-position: center center !important;
background-position: center center !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
-webkit-background-size: cover !important;
-moz-background-size: cover !important;
-o-background-size: cover !important;
background-size: cover !important;
-webkit-background-attachment: fixed !important;
-moz-background-attahcment: fixed !important;
-o-background-attachment: fixed !important;
background-attachment: fixed !important;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code and all is correct. The background-attachment: fixed feature has been disabled in the mobile browsers.

For detail : [How to replicate background-attachment fixed on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios)

Comment: all of those will apply to the whole website. I want it to apply to my specific section. I tried to set those fixed on `#biography` section but no luck.