# Background image not showing on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I have a div with a background image applied dynamically with JS. It works great except in iOS - both in iOS Safari & iOS Chrome, the background image just doesn't show. Very weird I didn't find any answer for that online.
Here is how it looks normally:

[image]

And here it how it looks on iOS (ipad and iphone):

[image]

Here is the CSS, the background-image value was applied by JS:

```
.NavFrame {
  width: 104px;
  height: 58px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-right: 2%;
  background-image: url(http://www.test.com/test.jpg);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE: Thank you all for the answers, however eventually it was some bug in my JS code. Anyway hope it can help someone else.

Comment: This issue is already discussed in stackoverflow pl. refer to the below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999660/background-image-not-showing-on-ipad-and-iphone

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
.NavFrame {
      width: 104px;
      height: 58px;
      background-position: center center;

      margin-right: 2%;
      background-image: url(http://www.test.com/test.jpg);
      background-size: cover; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `background-size` *after* `background-image`:

```
.NavFrame {
  width: 104px;
  height: 58px;
  margin-right: 2%;
  background-image: url(http://www.test.com/test.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Or shorthand:

```
.NavFrame {    
  background: url(http://www.test.com/test.jpg) center center / cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is already discussed in stackoverflow pl. refer to the below link
[Background image not showing on iPad and iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999660/background-image-not-showing-on-ipad-and-iphone)